# Java Rest Request Handle multiple parameters

Tags: java, rest, http, parameters

My question looks like this:
it's kind of hard to explain because so many forums are handling this kind of problem but none of the answers does the trick for me.

I am using java and i want to build a restful service. I am using this:

```
URI uri = new URIBuilder()
                .setScheme("http")
                .setHost("localhost")
                .setPort(8080)
                .setPath("/search")
                .setParameter("first", "hello")
                .setParameter("second", "world,out")
                .setParameter("third", "there")
                .build();
```

What i get as URI is = 
http://localhost:8081/search?first=hello&second=world%2Cout&third=there

So and now i want to access the this data inside the URI like this:

```
@GET
@Path("search/")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String test(@PathParam("first") String first, @PathParam("second") String second,@PathParam("third") String third) {
    return first+second+third;
}
```

But all i get is :  Failed : HTTP error code : 404

So i think my handler for this request is not the way it should be. I tried so many different things but no way.

I hope somebody can explain me how to access the data in the right way.
thanks for any help.

EDIT: THIS is my controller :

```
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
          context.setContextPath("/");

          Server jettyServer = new Server(8081);
          jettyServer.setHandler(context);

          ServletHolder jerseyServlet = context.addServlet(
               org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, "/*");
          jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);

          jerseyServlet.setInitParameter(
             "jersey.config.server.provider.classnames",
             RestfulFarmingGameService.class.getCanonicalName());
```

Working with jetty and jersey. Thats all i've got.

Comment: Have you set any `contextPath` or any path with `@Controller` annotation?

Comment: PathParam is for... path parameters (`/search/{first}/{second}/{third}`). You want QueryParam.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `JAX-RS` Then you may try this way too.

The idea of matrix parameters is that they are an arbitrary set of name-value pairs embedded in
a uri path segment. A matrix parameter example is:

```
GET http://host.com/library/book;name=EJB 3.0;author=Bill Burke
```

The basic idea of matrix parameters is that it represents resources that are addressable by their
attributes as well as their raw id. The `@MatrixParam` annotation allows you to inject URI matrix
paramters into your method invocation

```
 @GET
public String getBook(@MatrixParam("name") String name, @MatrixParam("author") String
author) {...}
```

When the input request body is of the type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", a.k.a. an HTML
Form, you can inject individual form parameters from the request body into method parameter
values.

```
<form method="POST" action="/resources/service">
First name:
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<br>
Last name:
<input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>

   @Path("/resources/service")
@POST
public void addName(@FormParam("firstname") String first, 
        @FormParam("lastname") String
last) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using **@PathParam** , so your params must go in the url path like this: http://localhost:8080/search/first/second/third

if you want send using url params like ?first=somethin&second=something else... and so on you have to use **@RequestParam** instead of **@PathVariable**

```
@GET
@Path("search/")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String test(@RequestParam("first") String first, @RequestParam("second") String second,@RequestParam("third") String third) {
    return first+second+third;
}
```